# ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I am trying to install `upstox`, which is a Python API for connecting to market data. I am unable to install it on Python3.5.

My config is 
`Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 15:51:26) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`. And the error I keep getting is:

```
Collecting upstox
  Using cached upstox-0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future (from upstox)
  Using cached future-0.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting websocket-client (from upstox)
  Using cached websocket_client-0.42.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycurl (from upstox)
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0-cp35-none-win32.whl
Collecting enum (from upstox)
  Using cached enum-0.4.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import platform
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\platform.py", line 117, in <module>
        import sys, os, re, subprocess
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 50, in <module>
        import signal
      File "C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\signal.py", line 4, in <module>
        from enum import IntEnum as _IntEnum
    ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\enum\
```

Comment: This is currently an open bug https://github.com/upstox/upstox-python/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

for python2

```
sudo pip2 install -U enum
```

for python3

```
sudo pip3 install -U enum34
```

Answer (score 1):

for python2, we need both enum and enum34

`pip install enum`

`pip install enum34`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install enum34
```

will solve the issue

Comment: Installing enum34 is not necessary for Python versions >= 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

i named file as enum.py and recive that result
rename and all

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed `enum` before installing your desired package? It looks like it wants you to install it first.

Run this command in CMD to install `enum`, and then try installing your desired package:

```
pip install enum
```

Comment: I thought .whl takes care of whatever is required. Anyways: I tried installing enum and I get

Comment: Collecting enum
  Using cached enum-0.4.6.tar.gz
    ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'
    
    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\UserPad\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\enum\

Comment: `enum`  is part of the standard library and doesn't need to be installed. What happens if you do that import manually in a console session?

Comment: Then it looks like something has installed another module called `enum` that is masking the standard library module. At a guess, it is the Pypi module `enum 0.4.6`. It provided support for enums in versions of Python prior to 3.4. See if you can find it and uninstall it.