# A weird "ImportError" about IntEnum

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, lib

Today I want to setup [CTFd](https://github.com/CTFd/CTFd) on Ubuntu 16.04, yet I run into a weird ImportError. Having read [ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666136/importerror-cannot-import-name-intenum) and tried all the solutions I can get, I found the error still unsolved.

```
root@iZbp16wvcnnjq61mspee7aZ:/var/www/CTFd# pip install enum34 //As you can see, I have tried to install enum34 :( 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/pypi/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.1.8)
root@iZbp16wvcnnjq61mspee7aZ:/var/www/CTFd# python serve.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serve.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/var/www/CTFd/CTFd/__init__.py", line 223, in create_app
    from CTFd.api import api
  File "/var/www/CTFd/CTFd/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_restplus import Api
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restplus/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import fields, reqparse, apidoc, inputs, cors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restplus/fields.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .errors import RestError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restplus/errors.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._http import HTTPStatus
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restplus/_http.py", line 6, in <module>
    from enum import IntEnum
ImportError: cannot import name IntEnum  // THE PROBLEM!
```

Comment: You're using Python 2.7, which doesn't have enum and, as the message tells you, is EoL.

Comment: check if you have `pip3` and `python3` to work with Python 3 instead of `Python 2`

Comment: What version of `flask_restplus` are you using? Can you update to the latest one and try?

Comment: So...could you tell me how to avoid this problem？Should I enter some other codes but "python serve.py" to run it by using Python 3?  Thanks but please tell me more, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: First thing to check would be whether you have python 3 installed on your machine. As furas advised, you can try to run `python3 -V`. If it returns a "command not found", you'll have to install python3. Python 2 is deprecated anyway so you'd better work with python 3

Comment: Switch to Python 3.5 now, but when I ran serve.py(necessary for opening CTFd) by "python3 serve.py", a SyntaxError occurred. Is there any way to solve this problem with Python 2.7 :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Python 2.7 doesn't have `enum`, true, but the OP is using `enum34` to make up for it.  (Which was temporarily broken, but is fixed in 1.1.9.)

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar problem this morning and pinned enum34 to 1.1.6 - they release 1.1.8 last night and it seems to be a relatively empty package for some reason. But pinning to 1.1.6 worked for us.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by an issue with the recent release of the enum34 package: https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/enum34/issues/27/enum34-118-broken
As suggested, a fix for this can be to pin its version to 1.1.6 which is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed in `enum34 1.1.9`.